# Jmeter functions not working on linux

Tags: jmeter

In user defined variable I have set path for my file to be generated:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\MyDesktop\AutoPractice\/${__property(SVN)}_JMETER_API_${__time(yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss,)}.xls
```

This gives output as : `121_JMETER_API_2017-05-08_18-03-02`
Jmeter function is working fine on local set up.

However, on linux variable path is changed to:

```
/home/username/JMETER/Result/${__property(SVN)}_JMETER_API_${__time(yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss,)}.xls
```

This gives output as: `SVN_JMETER_API_2017-05-08_18-03-02`

Comment: The `__property(SVN)` function returns the value of property "SVN". If the property value cannot be found, and no default has been supplied, it returns the property name: "SVN". So, how do you configure "SVN" property in your Windows setup?

Comment: @Hugues Moreau , In beanshell post processor i have written props.put("SVN",SVNID1);